# Converting list of list to Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a transaction data "data" as :

```
 [ ["a","e","l"],["f","a","e","m","n"], ...]
```

Each sublist represent the single transaction. There is no header. I am trying to run FPGrowth algorithm using pyspark.

I tried the following way:

````py
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["items"])
print("1.Here")
fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.9, minConfidence=0.9)

model = fpGrowth.fit(df)

# Display frequent itemsets.
model.freqItemsets.show()

# Display generated association rules.
model.associationRules.show()


# transform examines the input items against all the association rules and summarize the
# consequents as prediction
model.transform(df).show()```
````

The error that I am getting is::

> ```
> IllegalArgumentException: 
> 'requirement failed: The input column must be array, but got string.'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame is not interpreted correctly, try using data in the following format:

```
data = [ (["a","e","l"],),(["f","a","e","m","n"],) ]
```